# Singular pronoun in "The Cardinal and Ferdinand… he warns her”

Tags: grammatical-number, sentence

> The Cardinal and Ferdinand, the brothers of the Duchess, are very much against her re-marriage. He even warns her by showing his father's dagger and that he would use it to take revenge on her if necessary.

[source](http://www.studymode.com/essays/Discuss-The-Duchess-Of-Malfi-As-170461.html)

1. I think the first sentence would be "The Cardinal and the Ferdinand...(they are two person and for this they are taking plural verb"are" in the above sentence  (sentence 1). My problem is coming to the second sentence, beginning with the pronoun *he*. If we consider the first sentence plural,then why we are using *he*?
2. I don't understand the structure of the above sentence *He even warns her by showing his father's dagger and "that" he would use it to take revenge on her if necessary.* Why we are using *that*?

Comment: The Cardinal is correct (because Cardinal is a title). "The Ferdinand" is incorrect, because Ferdinand is a proper name. Presumably the "he" refers to the brother (Ferdinand), because a Cardinal wouldn't carry a dagger (and presumably wouldn't take revenge).

Comment: right.then why we are using plural verb, sir?

Comment: Which sentence? The second sentence seems incorrect (pronoun without a clear antecedent). The first sentence seems to be correct (and has a plural verb).

Comment: It's a (very) badly written synopsis - try this one http://www.123helpme.com/duchess-of-malfi-by-john-webster-as-a-revenge-tragedy--view.asp?id=168557 All will become clear.

Comment: coordinating conjunction "and" added one antecedent,because there is only one "the" before and after "and".so, i think, it is singular,sir

Comment: With regard to your second question:  If you remove *and*, the sentence will make sense.  *That* is necessary; it is acting as a complimentizer.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion seems to come from assuming the second sentence is correct, and the first is wrong. I think in truth it is the other way around, though "wrong" is perhaps a little strong.

In regards to your specific questions:

1. "The Cardinal and the Ferdinand" would be incorrect. There are
   indeed two people here, "The Cardinal" which is a title has a
   definite article, and Ferdinand, another person, is a personal name
   and consequently does not take the article. It uses a plural verb
   because there are two brothers involved, as is clear from the two
   names and the fact that "brothers" is plural.
2. The second sentence is not well written, in fact it is ambiguous.
   He, being singular needs a clearer antecedent. The obvious
   antecedent is the two brothers, but the singular pronoun excludes
   this. So you are left to guess which of the two brothers is
   indicated from the context. There isn't an obvious way to do so from
   the context you give, so the sentence is really quite poorly
   written.

Better would be either:

```
The Cardinal even warns her by showing his father's dagger...
```

or

```
Ferdinand even warns her by showing his father's dagger...
```

After which the signular pronoun is crystal clear.

Answer (score -1):

I won't rehash the discussion concerning the ambiguous 'he' in the second sentence, which has already been amply covered.

However, I will comment on the awkwardness of using the same verb, *warns,* to apply both to showing the dagger and using it to take revenge; it would be much more elegant to include a second verb. Equally, *shows* would benefit from having an explicit subject:

> He even warns her by showing **her** his father's dagger and **indicating** that he would use it to take revenge on her if necessary.

Comment: Not only do I think the sentence (with the *"he"* corrected) is perfectly fine, but I don't follow your logic on the awkwardness of using the same verb to apply to two things. People do this all the time in English.